# Error: missing argument: in Contract constructor

Tags: solidity, contract-development, hardhat, chainlink

Documenting a solution to this error I received while working on a Chainlink contract:

**Error Message**

```
Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=1, expectedCount=2, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)...

reason: 'too many arguments:  in Contract constructor',
  code: 'UNEXPECTED_ARGUMENT',
  count: 1,
  expectedCount: 0
```

Answer (score 13):

**My Solution**

This problem occurred with Hardhat. The number of arguments in the contract constructor needed to match the number of arguments in the .deploy() method of the deployment script.

**Correct Implementation**

```
// CONTRACT FILE

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
 
   constructor() { // <——— Has 0 arguments
        console.log("Hey!");
    }
}

// DEPLOYMENT SCRIPT

async function main() {
    const APIConsumer = await ethers.getContractFactory("APIConsumer");
    const apiConsumer = await APIConsumer.deploy();  // <——— Must also have 0 arguments

    await apiConsumer.deployed();

    console.log(`APIConsumer deployed to: ${apiConsumer.address}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in hardhat The number of arguments in the contract constructor needed to match the number of arguments in the .deploy() method of the deployment script.